# Is there a clang++/libc++ equivalent to the __gnu_cxx::__freeres hook?

Tags: c++, hook, clang++, libc++

Does anyone know if clang++/libc++ has an equivalent to __gnu_cxx::__freeres?

(this is a hook that allows tools to trigger deallocation of resources such as memory allocated for exception handling to be used in case malloc fails, see [here](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/gcc/patch/20160224183558.GF4664@redhat.com/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of.

The exception pool (in libc++abi, not libc++) is not on the heap, anyway.

Comment: OK thanks. I won't fret about calling such a function for libc++abi from Valgrind then.